code autocomplete does not work in *.tsx files in Android Studio
When I start typing "View" and press tab, it just adds the word "View", but does not expand the structure like:

<.View> <./View>

dots for because it doesn't show the text without them
I tried:

install some plugins from the search list: react native, typescript, javascript
checked in Code autocomplete to see if there are any settings there, but there is no Typescript or Javascript option at all.
no needed language
Tried creating a file with html extension and expand something there, like a  tag for example, and everything works.
I just wrote a div, pressed tab and it expanded into <.div> <./div>.
I would like to achieve the same behavior in tsx files as well, but the local components don't want to expand like tags in html


Android Studio is based on/a fork of JetBrain's Intellj Community Edition with additional Android stuff (or perhaps more accurately non-Android stuff removed). From: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javascript-specific-guidelines.html it looks like JetBrains may be keeping additional APIs for Javascript/Typescript/NodeJS for Intellij Ultimate (paid product) or WebStorm.
